# Show some custom text before legends in DevExpress ASP.NET charts

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, devexpress, data-visualization

Our client need to show some custom text before legends in DevExpress ASP.NET charts **version 15**. Is there a property for that?

[image: Show some custom text before legends]

I've tried `diagram.AxisX.Title.Text = "axis title\n legend custom text"` and 
`series.LegendText = "legend custom text";` but both doesn't seems to be fulfilling the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

> This applies to version 16+

Per the official [DevExpress support](https://www.devexpress.com/support/center/Question/Details/T400202), one can use [`LegendTitle`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/clsDevExpressXtraChartsLegendTitletopic) for this purpose.